# Circular Explosion with Particles

Tags: c++

I currently have a Particle System written in C++ that I use to create Fireworks that each have 500 particles. I currently make them explode by giving each particle a random velocity between two numbers with the following code:

```
vel = new glm::vec3[numParticles];

for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++){
        vel[i] = glm::vec3((rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f, (rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f, (rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f);
    }
```

This makes them explode in a rectangular shape but I would like them to explode in a circular shape the same way real fireworks explode. I cannot seem to work out how to calculate each X, Y and Z for a circular explosion. Are there any formulas out there for this?

Thanks, Conor

Comment: If you know the center of the burst, you can randomly sample a velocity (magnitude) and angles theta and omega (rotation from each plane). Then turn your polar coordinate vectors (v, theta, omega) into Cartesian coordinate vectors (x,y,z) using trigonometry.

Comment: NOTE: `(rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f` will not produce a uniform distribution. If you would like one, there are classes that allow for such in [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: It's elementary, Watson...

Answer (score 0):

Normalize it. This makes the particle velocities unit length, which means they will explode in a roughly circular pattern.

```
vel = new glm::vec3[numParticles];

for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++){
        vel[i] = glm::normalize(glm::vec3((rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f, (rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f, (rand() % 1500 - 750) / 10000.0f));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use spherical coordinates to give them a random magnitude, theta, and omega.  Then you can convert those to XYZ.  This site should have all the formulas you need

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.